# Data Corruption with std::cin>>

Tags: c++, arrays, char, cin, memory-corruption

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int a=3;
    char ch[5];
    
    std::cout<<&a<<"\n"<<(void*)(ch)<<"\n";
    
    long int k1=strtol("0x70fe14",nullptr,16); // 7405076
    long int k2=strtol("0x70fe00",nullptr,16); // 7405056
    
    std::cout<<k1<<"\n"<<k2<<"\n";
    
    std::cout<<a<<"\n";
    std::cin>>ch;
    std::cout<<a<<"\n";
    
    std::cout<<ch<<"\n";
        
}
```

**Output**

```
0x70fe14
0x70fe00
7405076
7405056
3
12345678912345678912 // I entered this input for cin>>ch
0
12345678912345678912
```

I entered 20 characters for input `cin>>ch` so they will acquire memory from `7405056-7405075` so why it is corrupting data of variable `a` whose memory address start from `7405076` ?

Comment: Null terminated string. You get an extra character: the null at the end.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson yeah I got it. I am still in surprise how I forgot that one.Thanks